# AngularJS: Upload image and save in local storage

Tags: javascript, angularjs, memory-management, local-storage, phonegap-build

Hi My current scenario is that: I want to have functionality like this: 
I want to to have a `<input type=file>` in my html and when i click on `submit` or `upload`. it move the file into local storage directory.. then after 4-5 file savings. it check that localstorage directory, read the files/images that are in the storage then upload to the specific URL.

Also i want to create the directory into localstorage too in the begining of application.

Comment: Do you really mean localstorage? It's a key-value database which is limited to a few megabytes. You should use `requestFileSystem` in your case to allocate a few megabytes first and use that as your file storage. Also I'm not sure what you mean with `after 4-5 saves`

Comment: @praszyk First of all thanks for your comment. I actually means i have a controller which upload file to server via `http` request. but besides upload i want to save those files to my local storage. and then in evening or after some hours or timer the controller checks whether how many files are there in that `particular directory` and then upload all those too via Http request then delete them too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use, FileReader api in browsers. And then save the resulting date encoded image to localstorage in a specified directory.

refer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FileReader

I have done something similar, but without localstorage. Might help.

https://github.com/jeremyrajan/photoStickerUpload (repo)
https://github.com/jeremyrajan/photoStickerdemo (demo)

This might help, as a lib: https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage (for localstorage)

Hope that helps!